# how to kill shell process in boot

Tags: shell, debian, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, debian-based

Since recently, I work on raspberry so I'm a noob. I wrote a shell script that runs my program to blink a LED by gpio in the boot.
Now when the raspbian boots show some log then my led start blinking and everything got stuck in this situation and I can't run the cmd.
Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash  
cd /root/Desktop  
./blink
```

My setup is:

```
#update-rc.d mystartup.sh defaults 100
```

What should I do now? I can't boot it and start GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
#!/bin/bash  
cd /root/Desktop  
./blink &
```

to run `blink` in the background?